# What is the usage of jqgrid search 'is in' and 'is not in'

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

What does 'is in' and 'is not in' mean in jqgrid search filter?

Comment: Could you give some example, references, maybe some context to what you're asking?

Comment: I'm only asking what is the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is in` and `is not in` are the equivalents of `contains` and `does not contain`, with the operands reversed. For example:

- `banana` *contains* `ban`,
- `banana` *does not contain* `bar`.
- `ban` *is in* `banana`,
- `bar` *is not in* `banana`.

In summary, these operators allow you to search for cells whose values are (or are not) part of a given string, instead of the other way around, searching for cells whose values contain (or do not contain) a given string.